# REST Verb for Enqueue and Dequeue

Tags: rest, http, asp.net-core

I'm implementing a REST'ish API that wraps a Queue. I need to Enqueue and Dequeue items. Normally I would use GET to query but in this case Dequeueing something will change the state by removing the item. So GET seems like a poor choice.

Is there a standard or recomendation for this use case? I thought about PUT and POST but I'm not sure which should be which.

I could use DELETE for Dequeue and PUT for Enqueue. That actually seems to make the most sense.

I'm implementing this in ASP.NET Core if that makes a difference.

Comment: Who will be using your API and will they really care about the verb being used?  It's always a developer dilemma...PUT or POST...not a user dilemma.  The user is unlikely to care.  Pick a verb and move on.

Comment: Ended up using POST and DELETE

Answer (score 0):

`PUT` for enqueue makes sense, since you're adding an item to the collection.  `GET` and `DELETE` in a REST-y context require you to specify which item you're talking about, or to operate on the whole collection, neither of which work for dequeueing.

One common solution for custom actions is to `POST` to `/collection/<action_name>`, so in your case, you could specify that you `POST`to `/collection/enqueue` and `/collection/dequeue` to do your work.

Alternatively, HTTP verbs are just text, and you're free to invent your own, so you could choose to `ENQUEUE` and `DEQUEUE` to `/collection`.

Comment: PUT is bad choice for enqueue. Put is meant for idempotent operations and queuing a message isn't idempotent until you have some kind of message id and your queue service can guarantee an **exactly once** or **at most once** semantics. POST is for non-idempotent operations, read: multiple POST calls with the same data will result in different states (multiple messages queued) whereas multiple PUT calls should result in the same state as the first call

Comment: I guess it depends whether the same item can appear in your queue more than once.

Comment: @Tseng That makes sense. So maybe POST and DELETE would be better?

Comment: DELETE doesn't completely match up either since its supposed to be idempotent also, ie you can delete X and deleting X again doesn't cause a different state from the first delete, but in the case of a dequeue calling DELETE twice does cause different state changes. I could do as @Simon suggests and just have 2 different POSTs but I was trying to go towards more simple api . I'm just a little surprised someone hasn't standardized this already as it seems a common operation. On the other hand, maybe I'm making a mountain out of a molehill.

Comment: @Zack: Dequeuing typically doesn't happen via RESTful api and if it does, its usually a 2-request operation. You get the items from the queue with "get" and remove it from the queue with delete (in terms of message queues it be called fetch and ack (acknowledge, confirms that the message was successfully processed and can be removed from the queue. Failing to ack a message keeps it staying in the queue until its acknowledged). But this doesn't map very well to the "web", due to its stateless nature)